# Avoid subquery to create a view

Tags: mysql

As stated in the title i need to create a view. but I have certain restraints from the enterprise: most notably I must try to create this view without the use of another view. Since the enterprise is using SQLyog the MySQL version is 5.7.4, which is incompatible with subquery.

the query is the following:

```
SELECT
`t1`.`idcontract`                    AS `idcontract`,
`t1`.`contract_number`               AS `contract_number`,
`t1`.`idbuildingunit`                AS `idbuildingunit`,
`t1`.`Trascurabile`                  AS `Trascurabile`,
`t1`.`Bassa`                         AS `Bassa`,
`t1`.`Media`                         AS `Media`,
`t1`.`Alta`                          AS `Alta`,
`t1`.`Molto_alta`                    AS `Molto_alta`,
`t1`.`Docu_completa`                 AS `Docu_completa`,
`t1`.`Docu_incompletaORdaverificare` AS `Docu_incompletaORdaverificare`,
`t1`.`Docu_mancante`                 AS `Docu_mancante`,
`t1`.`Docu_null`                     AS `Docu_null`,
MAX((CASE WHEN (`t1`.`Molto_alta` > 2) THEN 100
          WHEN ((`t1`.`Molto_alta` >= 1) AND (`t1`.`Alta` >= 1)) THEN 90
          WHEN ((`t1`.`Alta` > 2) OR ((`t1`.`Molto_alta` >= 1) AND (`t1`.`Media` >= 1))) THEN 80
          WHEN (((`t1`.`Molto_alta` >= 1) AND (`t1`.`Bassa` >= 1)) OR ((`t1`.`Alta` >= 1) AND (`t1`.`Media` >= 1))) THEN 70
          WHEN (((`t1`.`Molto_alta` >= 1) AND (`t1`.`Trascurabile` >= 1)) OR ((`t1`.`Alta` >= 1) AND (`t1`.`Bassa` >= 1)) OR (`t1`.`Media` > 2)) THEN 60
          WHEN (((`t1`.`Alta` >= 1) AND (`t1`.`Trascurabile` >= 1)) OR ((`t1`.`Media` >= 1) AND (`t1`.`Bassa` >= 1))) THEN 50
          WHEN (((`t1`.`Media` >= 1) AND (`t1`.`Trascurabile` >= 1)) OR (`t1`.`Bassa` > 2)) THEN 40
          WHEN ((`t1`.`Bassa` >= 1) AND (`t1`.`Trascurabile` >= 1)) THEN 30
          WHEN (`t1`.`Trascurabile` = 8) THEN 20
          ELSE 0 END)) AS `Criticita_posizione`,
MAX((CASE WHEN (`t1`.`Docu_mancante` > 3) THEN 100
          WHEN (`t1`.`Docu_mancante` > 2) THEN 90
          WHEN (`t1`.`Docu_mancante` > 1) THEN 80
          WHEN (`t1`.`Docu_incompletaORdaverificare` > 3) THEN 60
          WHEN ((`t1`.`Docu_mancante` > 0) OR (`t1`.`Docu_incompletaORdaverificare` > 2)) THEN 40
          WHEN (`t1`.`Docu_incompletaORdaverificare` >= 1) THEN 20
          ELSE 0 END)) AS `Criticita_docucomplete`
FROM (SELECT contract.idcontract      AS `idcontract`,
contract.`contract_number` AS `contract_number`,
buildingunit.`idbuildingunit`  AS `idbuildingunit`,
SUM((CASE WHEN (`judgement_criticity`.`judgement_criticity_score` = 'trascurabile') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) AS `Trascurabile`,
SUM((CASE WHEN (`judgement_criticity`.`judgement_criticity_score` = 'bassa') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) AS `Bassa`,
SUM((CASE WHEN (`judgement_criticity`.`judgement_criticity_score` = 'media') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) AS `Media`,
SUM((CASE WHEN (`judgement_criticity`.`judgement_criticity_score` = 'alta') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) AS `Alta`,
SUM((CASE WHEN (`judgement_criticity`.`judgement_criticity_score` = 'molto alta') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) AS `Molto_alta`,
SUM((CASE WHEN (`docucomplete`.`docu_complete` = 'Completa') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) AS `Docu_completa`,
SUM((CASE WHEN (`docucomplete`.`docu_complete` = 'Incompleta') THEN 1
          WHEN (`docucomplete`.`docu_complete` = 'Da verificare') THEN 1 
          ELSE 0 END)) AS `Docu_incompletaORdaverificare`,
SUM((CASE WHEN (`docucomplete`.`docu_complete` = 'Mancante') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) AS `Docu_mancante`,
SUM((CASE WHEN (`docucomplete`.`docu_complete` = '-') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) AS `Docu_null`
FROM (`contract`
       LEFT JOIN (`asset`
        LEFT JOIN (`buildingunit`
         LEFT JOIN (((((`analysisjudgement`
                        JOIN `analysis` ON ((`analysisjudgement`.`idanalysis` = `analysis`.`idanalysis`)))
                       JOIN `analysis_type` ON ((`analysis`.`idanalysis_type` = `analysis_type`.`idanalysis_type`)))
                      JOIN `analysisresult` ON ((`analysisjudgement`.`idanalysisresult` = `analysisresult`.`idanalysisresult`)))
                     JOIN `judgement_criticity` ON ((`analysisjudgement`.`idjudgement_criticity` = `judgement_criticity`.`idjudgement_criticity`)))
                    JOIN `docucomplete` ON ((`analysisjudgement`.`iddocucomplete` = `docucomplete`.`iddocucomplete`)))
         ON ((`analysis`.`idbuildingunit` = `buildingunit`.`idbuildingunit`)))
        ON ((`buildingunit`.`idasset` = `asset`.`idasset`)))
       ON ((`asset`.`idcontract` = `contract`.`idcontract`)))
WHERE ((`analysis_type`.`analysis_type` <> 'Valorizzazione')
    OR ISNULL(`analysis_type`.`analysis_type`)) AND (`buildingunit`.`buildingunit_isgeneral` = 'yes')
    OR ISNULL(`buildingunit`.`buildingunit_isgeneral`)
GROUP BY contract.`idcontract`,contract.`contract_number`, buildingunit.`idbuildingunit`) `t1`
GROUP BY 
      `t1`.`idcontract`,`t1`.`contract_number`,`t1`.`idbuildingunit`,
      `t1`.`Trascurabile`,`t1`.`Bassa`,`t1`.`Media`,`t1`.`Alta`,
      `t1`.`Molto_alta`,`t1`.`Docu_completa`,
      `t1`.`Docu_incompletaORdaverificare`,
      `t1`.`Docu_mancante`,`t1`.`Docu_null`
```

I am a very first timer in mysql and still understanding commands and syntax. this query can of course be cleaned (it is one of my tasks), but my first concern is that i want to remove subqueries. is there a way to integrate the MAX functions with the SUM functions that are shown here? i mean something like making a MAX function out of a SUM function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm following your query correctly, then in its current form the `MAX()` function should be unnecessary.

In your subquery, you are grouping your data by `contract.idcontract`, `contract.contract_number`, and `buildingunit.idbuildingunit`. This ensures you'll get one row for each unique set of these three values in the subquery.

Then, in the outer query, you group by these same three fields again, plus all the fields you calculated using `SUM()`. however, you already have one unique row for every unique set of the first three values, so grouping on the rest of the values is unnecessary.

Since each grouped set of rows at this level will, in fact, be one row, the `MAX()` is unneeded - there's only one set of values to do the calculations one.

You should be able to confirm this fairly easily; modify your query by removing the last `GROUP BY` clause, and the `MAX()` functions around your two case statements. The results should be the same as what you get with the query as it stands now.

---

So, can we eliminate the subquery? Yes - but the result is not pretty.

Once you've modified the query as described above, the main purpose of the subquery is to allow us to refer to the various `SUM`s by a simple alias.

So, to get rid of the subquery, we need to modify the query further. We need to move the `FROM`, `WHERE`, and `GROUP BY` clauses from the subquery to the main query. And, we need to replace each of the `t1.<colname>` aliases with the appropriate `SUM()` (or column) from the subquery.

The results should look something like the below (I don't have your database, so I can't test it):

```
SELECT
contract.idcontract                                                                                      AS `idcontract`,
contract.`contract_number`                                                                               AS `contract_number`,
contract.`contract_number`                                                                               AS `idbuildingunit`,
SUM((CASE WHEN (`judgement_criticity`.`judgement_criticity_score` = 'trascurabile') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END))  AS `Trascurabile`,
SUM((CASE WHEN (`judgement_criticity`.`judgement_criticity_score` = 'bassa') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END))         AS `Bassa`,
SUM((CASE WHEN (`judgement_criticity`.`judgement_criticity_score` = 'media') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END))         AS `Media`,
SUM((CASE WHEN (`judgement_criticity`.`judgement_criticity_score` = 'alta') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END))          AS `Alta`,
SUM((CASE WHEN (`judgement_criticity`.`judgement_criticity_score` = 'molto alta') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END))    AS `Molto_alta`,
SUM((CASE WHEN (`docucomplete`.`docu_complete` = 'Completa') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END))                         AS `Docu_completa`,
SUM((CASE WHEN (`docucomplete`.`docu_complete` = 'Incompleta') THEN 1
          WHEN (`docucomplete`.`docu_complete` = 'Da verificare') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END))                    AS `Docu_incompletaORdaverificare`,
SUM((CASE WHEN (`docucomplete`.`docu_complete` = 'Mancante') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END))                         AS `Docu_mancante`,
SUM((CASE WHEN (`docucomplete`.`docu_complete` = '-') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END))                                AS `Docu_null`,
(CASE WHEN (SUM((CASE WHEN (`judgement_criticity`.`judgement_criticity_score` = 'molto alta') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) > 2) THEN 100
      WHEN ((SUM((CASE WHEN (`judgement_criticity`.`judgement_criticity_score` = 'molto alta') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) >= 1) AND (SUM((CASE WHEN (`judgement_criticity`.`judgement_criticity_score` = 'alta') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) >= 1)) THEN 90
      WHEN ((SUM((CASE WHEN (`judgement_criticity`.`judgement_criticity_score` = 'alta') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) > 2) OR ((SUM((CASE WHEN (`judgement_criticity`.`judgement_criticity_score` = 'molto alta') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) >= 1) AND (SUM((CASE WHEN (`judgement_criticity`.`judgement_criticity_score` = 'media') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) >= 1))) THEN 80
      WHEN (((SUM((CASE WHEN (`judgement_criticity`.`judgement_criticity_score` = 'molto alta') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) >= 1) AND (SUM((CASE WHEN (`judgement_criticity`.`judgement_criticity_score` = 'bassa') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) >= 1)) OR ((SUM((CASE WHEN (`judgement_criticity`.`judgement_criticity_score` = 'alta') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) >= 1) AND (SUM((CASE WHEN (`judgement_criticity`.`judgement_criticity_score` = 'media') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) >= 1))) THEN 70
      WHEN (((SUM((CASE WHEN (`judgement_criticity`.`judgement_criticity_score` = 'molto alta') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) >= 1) AND (SUM((CASE WHEN (`judgement_criticity`.`judgement_criticity_score` = 'trascurabile') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) >= 1)) OR ((SUM((CASE WHEN (`judgement_criticity`.`judgement_criticity_score` = 'alta') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) >= 1) AND (SUM((CASE WHEN (`judgement_criticity`.`judgement_criticity_score` = 'bassa') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) >= 1)) OR (SUM((CASE WHEN (`judgement_criticity`.`judgement_criticity_score` = 'media') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) > 2)) THEN 60
      WHEN (((SUM((CASE WHEN (`judgement_criticity`.`judgement_criticity_score` = 'alta') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) >= 1) AND (SUM((CASE WHEN (`judgement_criticity`.`judgement_criticity_score` = 'trascurabile') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) >= 1)) OR ((SUM((CASE WHEN (`judgement_criticity`.`judgement_criticity_score` = 'media') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) >= 1) AND (SUM((CASE WHEN (`judgement_criticity`.`judgement_criticity_score` = 'bassa') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) >= 1))) THEN 50
      WHEN (((SUM((CASE WHEN (`judgement_criticity`.`judgement_criticity_score` = 'media') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) >= 1) AND (SUM((CASE WHEN (`judgement_criticity`.`judgement_criticity_score` = 'trascurabile') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) >= 1)) OR (SUM((CASE WHEN (`judgement_criticity`.`judgement_criticity_score` = 'bassa') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) > 2)) THEN 40
      WHEN ((SUM((CASE WHEN (`judgement_criticity`.`judgement_criticity_score` = 'bassa') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) >= 1) AND (SUM((CASE WHEN (`judgement_criticity`.`judgement_criticity_score` = 'trascurabile') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) >= 1)) THEN 30
      WHEN (SUM((CASE WHEN (`judgement_criticity`.`judgement_criticity_score` = 'trascurabile') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) = 8) THEN 20
      ELSE 0 END) AS `Criticita_posizione`,
(CASE WHEN (SUM((CASE WHEN (`docucomplete`.`docu_complete` = 'Mancante') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) > 3) THEN 100
      WHEN (SUM((CASE WHEN (`docucomplete`.`docu_complete` = 'Mancante') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) > 2) THEN 90
      WHEN (SUM((CASE WHEN (`docucomplete`.`docu_complete` = 'Mancante') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) > 1) THEN 80
      WHEN (SUM((CASE WHEN (`docucomplete`.`docu_complete` = 'Incompleta') THEN 1 WHEN (`docucomplete`.`docu_complete` = 'Da verificare') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) > 3) THEN 60
      WHEN ((SUM((CASE WHEN (`docucomplete`.`docu_complete` = 'Mancante') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) > 0) OR (SUM((CASE WHEN (`docucomplete`.`docu_complete` = 'Incompleta') THEN 1 WHEN (`docucomplete`.`docu_complete` = 'Da verificare') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) > 2)) THEN 40
      WHEN (SUM((CASE WHEN (`docucomplete`.`docu_complete` = 'Incompleta') THEN 1 WHEN (`docucomplete`.`docu_complete` = 'Da verificare') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) >= 1) THEN 20
      ELSE 0 END) AS `Criticita_docucomplete`
FROM (`contract`
       LEFT JOIN (`asset`
        LEFT JOIN (`buildingunit`
         LEFT JOIN (((((`analysisjudgement`
                        JOIN `analysis` ON ((`analysisjudgement`.`idanalysis` = `analysis`.`idanalysis`)))
                       JOIN `analysis_type` ON ((`analysis`.`idanalysis_type` = `analysis_type`.`idanalysis_type`)))
                      JOIN `analysisresult` ON ((`analysisjudgement`.`idanalysisresult` = `analysisresult`.`idanalysisresult`)))
                     JOIN `judgement_criticity` ON ((`analysisjudgement`.`idjudgement_criticity` = `judgement_criticity`.`idjudgement_criticity`)))
                    JOIN `docucomplete` ON ((`analysisjudgement`.`iddocucomplete` = `docucomplete`.`iddocucomplete`)))
         ON ((`analysis`.`idbuildingunit` = `buildingunit`.`idbuildingunit`)))
        ON ((`buildingunit`.`idasset` = `asset`.`idasset`)))
       ON ((`asset`.`idcontract` = `contract`.`idcontract`)))
WHERE ((`analysis_type`.`analysis_type` <> 'Valorizzazione')
    OR ISNULL(`analysis_type`.`analysis_type`)) AND (`buildingunit`.`buildingunit_isgeneral` = 'yes')
    OR ISNULL(`buildingunit`.`buildingunit_isgeneral`)
GROUP BY contract.`idcontract`,contract.`contract_number`, buildingunit.`idbuildingunit`
```

(I warned you it was ugly).

If this worked correctly, you should get the same results with this query as with the original.

If you've been following along, for the sake of maintainability, you may want to keep the modified version of the query (with the subquery in it), and use that to make changes as you need to. Then, do the replacement of all the `t1` values with the actual column/calculation from the subquery (as I did) to build the new production query. That way, for development purposes, you've still got each `SUM()` in one place only, and don't have to worry about only updating it in five of the six places it shows up in the final query.

Side note: I believe you may be missing a set of parentheses in your `WHERE` clause - I suspect that the two checks on `buildingunit.buildingunit_isgeneral` should be grouped together.

Comment: Ok yesterday I tried the query. other than some little errors (normal since you do not have the database), that were easy to find, it worked fine! It was basically what I was trying to do, apart form the fact that i was trying to re-insert that MAX function on the SUM functions for the algorithm. Thank you very much, it helped me understanding something more, and better too.

Answer (score 0):

`MAX()` like other aggregate functions is a common trap for a newbies.

When you query the `MAX()` you do not get the row where some value is maximal. You simply get the maximal value while all other columns have unrelated and unpredictable values.

Let there be table A with two columns:

```
+----+-------+
| id | value |
+----+-------+
|  1 |     2 |
|  2 |     5 |
|  3 |     1 |
|  4 |     7 |
|  5 |     3 |
+----+-------+
```

and the query:

```
SELECT id, MAX(value) AS maxvalue
  FROM a
;
```

May be you expect that query return the next line:

```
+----+----------+
| id | maxvalue |
+----+----------+
|  4 |        7 |
+----+----------+
```

but in fact result will be like that:

```
+----+----------+
| id | maxvalue |
+----+----------+
|  1 |        7 |
+----+----------+
```

That happens because aggregate functions do not fetch the whole row but only aggregated `value`. 7 is the maximum for `value`, but if you want to get the whole row you need a subselect:

```
SELECT id, value
  FROM a
 WHERE value = (SELECT MAX(value) FROM a)
;
```

Therefore if you want to filter rows by some aggregate function like `MAX()` you definitely need a subselects. Or you have to modify your database in some way to avoid calling the `MAX()`